# How to pass arbitrary argument with pnpm

Tags: pnpm, turborepo

With npm, you can pass random arguments like this:

```
  npm run build --foo="bar"
```

You can then access `foo` value this way:

```
   process.env.npm_config_foo
```

Is it possible to do the same with pnpm? I looked in their docs but couldn't find anything on that. I tried something like this but getting *unknown flag* error

```
   pnpm build --foo=bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why it throws an error. Sounds like a bug. However, this will work:

```
pnpm run build --foo=bar
```

But it will not create the `npm_config_foo` env variable. It will just append the option to the executed script. So if your build script is `webpack`, then pnpm will run:

```
webpack --foo=bar
```

So, it is basically like running `npm run build -- --foo=bar`. Or like running `yarn build --foo=bar`

You can read about this also in the pnpm docs: https://pnpm.io/cli/run#options

Comment: You actually just saving my life